# how to GET and POST on Twitter or facebook in ruby on rails using access tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, twitter-oauth, omniauth

I am using omniauth to authenticate a user via twitter, now as mentioned by twitter API REST architecture, I need to send a GET or POST request to Twitter

[twitter api documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) !
I am not able to find a good tutorial for this.

Even for facebook if I want to GET or POST, how do I do that ?
Is there a generic way ?
Can anyone help ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the standard net/http library you could use, and several gems which enhance its functionality, providing a cleaner interface and (much) faster performance. I personally recommend Typhoeus, a gem for making these kinds of requests which is easy to use and much faster than the standard library.

https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus

Comment: can we use Rack or Action Dispatch ?